# Cookies not shared between expo-auth-session and react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, webview, expo

Im developing an expo react native app that uses our own Oauth2 provider implementation for authentication.  In the expo app, we are using expo-auth-session for the Oauth2 flow, which works fine.  When we trigger the flow using `useAuthRequest` we are prompted to allow the browser to open in iOS and then we log in and get redirected back with the access code, as we're supposed to, allowing us to request an access token and then make authorized requests.  All that works perfectly without issue.

The problem is that when we THEN try to use a webview to load a page from the same server we just logged into an authenticated, we're not logged in.  When we inspect it we see that the cookies are basically missing.  It appears that whatever was used for the `useAuthRequest` call is a completely different browser session than what is used for the `webview.`.

We tried using Expo's `web-browser` module as well and had the same issue.

How can we get the same browser to be used for authentication as we use for our Webview so when the user authenticates they are also logged into their account in the Webview?

Comment: Like you discovered cookies are not shared. Try to open a page url with Linking.openUrl: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking.